# Printing Vector Array with push_back

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c++11, vector

I'm trying to show the values of a dynamic array input using vector and a for range loop but when it prints it shows the 0's then the value that was input.

Please don't mind the if statement as I commented it out to use a smaller sample size when testing. But if I enter the size say its 3 then input values such as 1,2,3 the output would be 0 0 0 1 2 3. I'm trying to remove the first three 0's.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many numerical values do you wish to enter: ";
    int values, index, collect;
    std::cin >> values;
    std::vector<int> numbers(values);
    //if(values == 31)
    //{
        for (index = 0; index < values; index++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter value[" << (index + 1) << "]: ";
            std::cin >> collect;
            numbers.push_back(collect);
        }
        for (auto &showNumbers : numbers)
        {
            std::cout << showNumbers << " ";
        }
    //}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use std::vector<int> numbers; When you add the (values) you create a vector of zeros

Comment: Please read some documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 1):

This line creates a vector of `values` elements.

```
std::vector<int> numbers(values);
```

When you're entering the `3` as `values`, the vector will hold a three elements with values of `0`.

Then you're pushing 3 more elements:

```
numbers.push_back(collect);
```

You could either:

1. replace `std::vector<int> numbers(values);` with `std::vector<int> numbers;` (this will create empty vector), or
2. replace `numbers.push_back(collect);` with `numbers.at(index) = collect;` (this will set element value)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `numbers[index] = collect;` and you are good. You can even try this `cin >> numbers[index];`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a constructor in

```
std::vector<int> numbers(values);
```

In your case:

> values = 3

which sets the first 3 contents as zeros. Then using push_back you are adding values further. You must just declare the vector as:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
```